# Multilanguage Support CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I found this tutorial (http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-language-support-in-codeigniter/) to add multilanguage support to my website. I followed it step by step. However on changing the language I get the following error code:

Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on null in application/hooks/LanguageLoader.php on line 9

Obviously the saved language in my cookie can not be received? How do I fix this? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a second language to the site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097566/how-to-add-a-second-language-to-the-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates the that class that has the function userdata() is not initialized - NULL. In this case userdata() is part of the Session class.

I don't see that class being loaded anywhere in the tutorial so try this version for LangSwitch.php controller

```
<?php
class LangSwitch extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('session');
      $this->load->helper('url');
  }

  function switchLanguage($language = "") {
      $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
      $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
      redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```